# How do I escape an ! so terminal sees a closing dquote for echo "Hello World!"

Tags: terminal, escaping, double-quotes

**The problem:**

By typing, `echo "Hello World!"`, into the terminal I'm am answered with: `dquote>`

**The Question (2-parts):**

If I use single quotes, terminal returns the result that I'm expecting to see: `Hello World!`

1. How do you escape an `!`?
2. Why are double quotes different than single quotes here?

**I have tried:**

Using backslash, `echo "Hello World/!"` doesn't seem to work, I'm still returned `dquote>`.
I've also tried looking for other answers on escape characters and stackoverflow answers. They usually end up going over my head.

Comment: `/` is a forward slash.

Comment: Haha!! Nice catch! Thanks so much this solved everything!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**About question 1: (*How do you escape an `!`?*)**

You can use `"'!'"`

*Example:*

```sh
echo "Hello World"'!'""'!'" I'm there."
```

*Result:*

```
Hello World!! I'm there.
```

---

**About question 2: (*Why are double quotes different than single quotes here?*)**

Because `!` is the default "history expansion" character and inside double quotes "history expansion" is performed.

*Bash manual:*

> [3.1.2.2 Single Quotes](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Single-Quotes.html)
>
> Enclosing characters in single quotes (`'`) preserves the literal value of each character within the quotes. A single quote may not occur between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.
>
> [3.1.2.3 Double Quotes](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html)
>
> Enclosing characters in double quotes (`"`) preserves the literal value of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of `$`, `` ` ``, `\`, and, when history expansion is enabled, `!`. The characters `$` and `` ` `` retain their special meaning within double quotes (see [Shell Expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html#Shell-Expansions)). The backslash retains its special meaning only when followed by one of the following characters: `$`, `` ` ``, `"`, `\`, or newline. Within double quotes, backslashes that are followed by one of these characters are removed. Backslashes preceding characters without a special meaning are left unmodified. A double quote may be quoted within double quotes by preceding it with a backslash. If enabled, **history expansion will be performed unless an `!` appearing in double quotes is escaped using a backslash. The backslash preceding the `!` is not removed.**
>
> The special parameters `*` and `@` have special meaning when in double quotes (see [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification of the differences between single quotes and double quotes in terminal Tom. That makes sense that double quote are evaluating the ! to mean history expansion where the single quotes are preserving its value.

Comment: @PixelWolfe if the answer fix your issue, can you mark the question as resolved.